# How to run activex control in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, activex, internet-explorer-10

I have an intranet application that uses activex. It runs fine in Windows 7 but not in Windows 8. I've used caspol to grant full trust, I've set IE 10 to allow downloading and running of activex controls.

I've even tried to run it in Chrome with an activex addon.

Nothing seems to work.

I'd really appreciate any insight. Jon

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how to get ActiveX controls to work in IE in the modern/metro interface, you're completely out of luck; ActiveX controls do not work there.

If you want to get an ActiveX control to work, you have to switch to the standard desktop and launch IE from there. ActiveX does work there. I use it to access Remote Desktop Web App.

Comment: Thanks, both you and Steven - I am running IE from the desktop and I have it set to IE9 compatibility mode. The control is in an object tag so it doesn't show up as a downloaded program. The object is being found by IE. I wrote the dll and the web page both have been working for over a year under Win 7 - Win 8 not so good so far.

Answer (score 0):

If the ActiveX control is written in .Net 3.5, you have to install that framework in Windows 8, as it is not included by default.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh506443(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score -1):

Try first to determine if the activex (cab or dll/ocx files) is downloaded to the user's browser.
You can use Fiddler for that.

Once you know the files ar actually downloaded you can tweak the browser's security settings to make sure the activex are installed.

You can see the installed activex programs under the %windir%\Downloaded Program Files" folder.

And try to lower the IE security settings for that site while you are troubleshooting this.